# Rails: Paperclip Gem triggers "Access Token must be used..." when rendering images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have an ongoing problem when trying to show images in my Rails view using the Paperclip gem. Whenever I try to render an image stored in my DB using      `<%= image_tag @event.image.url %>`    , allI get is the message "Graph returned an error. An Active access token must be used to query information about the current user".

Three things must be noted: 
1) Im a noob in Ruby on Rails. 
2) I have no user models nor any access_token requirements implemented in my app.
3) All other data is rendered just fine in the view, and apparently everything including the image is correctly passed into the DB.

Controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.json
  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /events/new
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  # GET /events/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /events
  # POST /events.json
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /events/1
  # PATCH/PUT /events/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /events/1
  # DELETE /events/1.json
  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :date, :address, :cost, :image, :description)
    end
end
```

Event Model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }#, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

'Show' View:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<%= image_tag @event.image.url %>


<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @event.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @event.date %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Address:</strong>
  <%= @event.address %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Cost:</strong>
  <%= @event.cost %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Image:</strong>
  <%= image_tag @event.image.url %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @event.description %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(@event) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', events_path %>
```

I truly appreciate your help as I've been stuck with this problem for a couple of days now.

Comment: Seems like you have a problem with your Facebook access token. You will find several similar questions and answers when you search for `Graph returned an error. An Active access token must be used to query information about the current user` on Google. I advise to check your Facebook and social tools configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @spickermann, but I don't have any social tools configuration since I'm not using them at all in my application. As I mentioned I don't even have a user model! I posted this question precisely because all I found by googling were problems with Facebook, which I'm not using right now.